# Filter and keep most recent duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Please help me with this one, I'm stuck and cant figure out how to write my Query. I'm working with SQL Server 2014.

Table A (approx 65k ROWS) CEID = primary key

```
 CEID     State    Checksum
    1        2          666
    2        2          666
    3        2          666
    4        2          333
    5        2          333
    6        9          333
    7        9          111
    8        9          111
    9        9          741
   10        2          656
```

Desired output

```
 CEID     State    Checksum
    3        2          666
    6        9          333
    8        9          111
    9        9          741
   10        2          656
```

I want to keep the row with highest CEID if "state" is equal for all duplicate checksums. If state differs but Checksum is equal i want to keep the row with highest CEID for State=9. Unique rows like CEID 9 and 10 should be included in result regardless of State.

This join returns all duplicates:

```
SELECT a1.*, a2.*
FROM  tableA a1  
INNER JOIN tableA a2 ON a1.ChecksumI = a2.ChecksumI
                     AND a1.CEID <> a2.CEID
```

I've also identified `MAX(CEID)` for each duplicate checksum with this query

```
SELECT a.Checksum, a.State, MAX(a.CEID) CEID_MAX ,COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tableA a
GROUP BY a.Checksum, a.State
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY a.Checksum, a.State
```

With the first query, I can't figure out how to `SELECT` the row with the highest `CEID` per Checksum.

The problem I encounter with last one is that GROUP BY isn't allowed in subqueries when I try to join on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with partition by `checksum` and order by `State desc` and `CEID desc`. Note both of your condition may be fulfill by `ORDER BY State desc, CEID desc`

And take the first row_number

```
;with 
cte as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (Partition by Checksum order by State desc, CEID desc)
    from    TableA
)
select  *
from    cte
where   rn = 1
order by CEID;
```